# Callback in function on JS ignore function order

Tags: javascript, dom-events, css-animations, settimeout, es6-promise

I tried to do some function that could wait for another function to finish first before they do their own. I've tried *callback* in function but it not work in any way. They still do these together. Here's my code :

```js
const mainContent = document.getElementById('mainContent');
const teleContent = document.getElementById('teleportHover');
const navbContent = document.getElementById('myNavbar');
const boutContent = document.getElementById('aboutme')


//Do animation first
const anima = (callback) => {
  lableRelease();
  sliderTopRelease();
  obmGo();
}

//Then Boom!
const teleDis = (callback) => {
  teleContent.style.opacity = '0';
  teleContent.style.transition = '1s';
}
const mainDis = (callback) => {
  mainContent.style.opacity = '0';
  mainContent.style.transition = '1s';
}
const removeOld = () => {
  mainContent.style.display = 'none';
}

flame.addEventListener('click', () => {
  anima(teleDis(mainDis(removeOld())));
})
```

Is there any other rules I missed? Or it doesn't work on my type of codes? If there's another way to do it please let me know

Comment: You're passing function calls, not functions: `anima(() => teleDis(() => mainDis(() => removeOld())));` Next you have to actually call the passed function; add `callback();` at the end of each function.

Comment: Ahh, this isn't how callbacks work. You're not even calling the callback functions you get.

Comment: You’re never invoking the callback in any of your functions. And even if you do, you are not awaiting for the transitions to complete. So everything will just happen at the same time.

Comment: The easiest, but not the most accurate way was to invoke the functions via [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout). The more complicated but callback based variant would listen to [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) events. And on top of the latter one could implement a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) based solution.

Comment: @Senzawa ... from the provided solutions/approaches are there any questions left?

Comment: @Senzawa ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the above comment ...

> *"The easiest, but not the most accurate way was to invoke the functions via [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout). The more complicated but callback based variant would listen to [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) events. And on top of the latter one could implement a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) based solution."*

Starting with the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) based approach ...

```js
function teleDis() {
  const teleContent = document
    .querySelector('#teleportHover');

  teleContent.style.opacity = '0';
  teleContent.style.transition = '1s';
}
function mainDis() {
  const mainContent = document
    .querySelector('#mainContent');

  mainContent.style.opacity = '0';
  mainContent.style.transition = '1s';
}
function removeOld() {
  document
    .querySelector('#mainContent')
    .style.display = 'none';
}

function handleAnimation() {
  // const navbContent = document.querySelector('#myNavbar');
  // const boutContent = document.querySelector('#aboutme');

  teleDis();
  setTimeout(mainDis, 1000);
  setTimeout(removeOld, 2000);

  // lableRelease();
  // sliderTopRelease();
  // obmGo();
}

function main() {
  document
    .querySelector('#flame')
    .addEventListener('click', handleAnimation)
}
main();
```

```html
<div id="myNavbar">navbContent</div>
<div id="teleportHover">teleContent</div>
<div id="mainContent">mainContent</div>
<div id="aboutme">boutContent</div>
<button id="flame">flame</button>
```

Utilizing [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) events ...

```js
function fadeOut(emNode) {
  emNode.classList.add('fadeout');
}
function ensureOpaque(emNode) {
  emNode.classList.add('opaque');
  emNode.classList.remove('fadeout');
}
function ensureOffDisplay(emNode) {
  emNode.classList.add('offDisplay');
  emNode.classList.remove('fadeout');
}

function handleAnimation() {
  const teleNode = document.querySelector('#teleportHover');
  const mainNode = document.querySelector('#mainContent');

  function proceedAfterMainAnimation(/*evt*/) {
    ensureOffDisplay(mainNode);
    mainNode.removeEventListener('animationend', proceedAfterMainAnimation);
  }
  function proceedAfterTeleAnimation(/*evt*/) {
    ensureOpaque(teleNode);
    teleNode.removeEventListener('animationend', proceedAfterTeleAnimation);

    mainNode.addEventListener('animationend', proceedAfterMainAnimation);
    fadeOut(mainNode);
  }
  teleNode.addEventListener('animationend', proceedAfterTeleAnimation);
  fadeOut(teleNode);
}

function main() {
  document
    .querySelector('#flame')
    .addEventListener('click', handleAnimation)
}
main();
```

```css
.offDisplay {
  display: none;
}
.opaque {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fadeout {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: fadeout;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myNavbar">navbContent</div>
<div id="teleportHover">teleContent</div>
<div id="mainContent">mainContent</div>
<div id="aboutme">boutContent</div>
<button id="flame">flame</button>
```

A possible [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) based solution ...

```js
function fadeOut(emNode) {
  emNode.classList.add('fadeout');
}
function ensureOpaque(emNode) {
  emNode.classList.add('opaque');
  emNode.classList.remove('fadeout');
}
function ensureOffDisplay(emNode) {
  emNode.classList.add('offDisplay');
  emNode.classList.remove('fadeout');
}

function createFadeoutPromise(elmNode) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    function handleAnimationEnd (/*evt*/) {
      elmNode.removeEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd);
      resolve();
    }
    elmNode.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd)
  });
  // return new Promise(resolve =>
  //   elmNode.addEventListener('animationend', resolve)
  // );
}

function handleAnimation() {
  const mainNode = document.querySelector('#mainContent');
  const teleNode = document.querySelector('#teleportHover');

  const promisedMainAnimation = createFadeoutPromise(mainNode);
  const promisedTeleAnimation = createFadeoutPromise(teleNode);

  promisedMainAnimation.then(() => {
    ensureOffDisplay(mainNode);
  });
  promisedTeleAnimation.then(() => {
    ensureOpaque(teleNode);
    fadeOut(mainNode);
  });
  fadeOut(teleNode);
}

function main() {
  document
    .querySelector('#flame')
    .addEventListener('click', handleAnimation)
}
main();
```

```css
.offDisplay {
  display: none;
}
.opaque {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fadeout {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: fadeout;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myNavbar">navbContent</div>
<div id="teleportHover">teleContent</div>
<div id="mainContent">mainContent</div>
<div id="aboutme">boutContent</div>
<button id="flame">flame</button>
```